# Automated Assembly/Disassemble library

Tags: binary-analysis, dynamic-analysis

I'm writing a handy reverse tool in C++ with manual assembling/disassembling shell, to automate my work!

I need an assembler library.
Is there any library, embedding in C++?

Comment: What exactly the library should do ? Disassembling ? Shell ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oleh Yuschuk released a light-weight open-source assembler library that you can download from http://ollydbg.de/srcdescr.htm

> **Assemble**
>
> Function Assemble(), as expected, converts command from ASCII
> form to binary 32 bit code.

Example:

```
  // Assemble one of the commands above. First try form with 32-bit immediate.
  pasm="ADD [DWORD 475AE0],1";
  printf("%s:\n",pasm);
  j=Assemble(pasm,0x400000,&am,0,0,errtext);
  n=sprintf(s,"%3i  ",j);
  for (i=0; i<j; i++) n+=sprintf(s+n,"%02X ",am.code[i]);
  if (j<=0) sprintf(s+n,"  error=\"%s\"",errtext);
  printf("%s\n",s);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can take one of these projects (I choose the alphabetic order to sort them):

### Assembler/Disassembler

- [GNU binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64, ARM, Sparc, MIPS, ...; **Formats**: ELF, Mach-O, PE (partial)).
- [Miasm](https://code.google.com/p/miasm/) (**Archs**: i386, ARM, PowerPC, MSP430; **Formats**: ELF, PE)
- [Metasm](http://metasm.cr0.org/) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64, PowerPC, MIPS; **Formats**: ELF, Mach-O (partial), PE)
- [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64; **Formats**: ELF, Mach-O, PE)
- [Radare2](http://www.radare.org/y/): [rasm](http://radare.org/y/?p=examples&f=rasm) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64, ARM, PowerPC, Sparc, MIPS, ...; **Formats**: ELF, Mach-O, PE)
- [srcdescr](http://ollydbg.de/srcdescr.htm) (**Archs**: i386; **Formats**: PE)
- [YASM](http://yasm.tortall.net/) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64; **Formats**: ELF, Mach-O, PE)

### Disassembler (only)

- [BAP](http://bap.ece.cmu.edu/) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64; **Formats**: ELF, PE)
- [BeaEngine](http://beatrix2004.free.fr/BeaEngine/index1.php) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64; **Formats**: PE)
- [Capstone Engine](http://www.capstone-engine.org/) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64, ARM, PowePC, Sparc, MIPS, ...; **Formats**: ELF, Mach-O, PE)
- [distorm](https://code.google.com/p/distorm/) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64)
- [ERESI](http://www.eresi-project.org/): [libasm](http://www.eresi-project.org/wiki/TheLibASM) (**Archs**: i386, ARM, Sparc, MIPS; **Formats**: ELF)
- [GDSL](https://code.google.com/p/gdsl-toolkit/wiki/Overview) (**Archs**: i386, MSP430, AVR)
- [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/tutorial.html) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64; **Formats**: ELF, Mach-O, PE)
- [Insight](https://insight.labri.fr/trac) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64, MSP430; **Formats**: ELF, PE (partial), Mach-O (partial))
- [libdasm](https://code.google.com/p/libdasm/) (**Archs**: i386)
- [libdisasm](http://bastard.sourceforge.net/libdisasm.html) (from [bastard](http://bastard.sourceforge.net/) project) (**Archs**: i386; **Formats**: ELF, PE)
- [Opdis](http://mkfs.github.io/content/opdis/) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64; **Formats**: ELF, Mach-O, PE)
- [Pyew](https://code.google.com/p/pyew/) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64; **Formats**: ELF, PE)
- [Udis86](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64)

### Assembler (only)

- [FASM](http://flatassembler.net/) (**Archs**: i386, AMD64; **Formats**: ELF, PE)

**EDIT**:
Each of these projects either contains a library that can be used as it is, or can be wrapped into a library that you will have to code by yourself with the features that you request.

Comment: thanks @perror for fast and informative answer, but I'm looking for **assembler** library. except _GDSL toolkit_ and _METASM_ ( that i don't know what exactly they are), others are disassemblers.

Comment: Then, you should look at Miasm and go a bit deeper in all the items. GAS (GNU ASsembler), NASM and others have also an assembler library inside.

Comment: Yeap! but NASM & GAS are not lib and extracting parser and assembler is not easy work! I'm looking for easy way!

Comment: You should definitely take a deeper look at all these projects. What you ask for is unclear and there is probably no such library. So, you will need some work at some point. Yet, Radare2, Miasm, GNU binutils and the ERESI project should contain everything you need (but maybe in a state that will require some work before being usable).

Comment: Radare2 can of course assemble :)

Comment: Most of these are *not* libraries.

Comment: Not a problem, in this case you can wrap a library around. But, if the authors of one of the cited project think that something is wrong, feel free to mention it (I am far from being perfect).